# Unable to create 3 tier-architecture

Tags: python

I have this code. I have to transform it into 3-tier architecture. But I am getting multiple errors such as: *TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute* and *TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable*.

```
## This key will serve all examples in this document.
KEY = "PASTE_YOUR_FACE_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY_HERE"

## This endpoint will be used in all examples in this quickstart.
ENDPOINT = "PASTE_YOUR_FACE_ENDPOINT_HERE"

## Create an authenticated FaceClient.
face_client = FaceClient(ENDPOINT, CognitiveServicesCredentials(KEY))

# Base url for the Verify and Facelist/Large Facelist operations
IMAGE_BASE_URL = 'https://csdx.blob.core.windows.net/resources/Face/Images/'

# Create a list to hold the target photos of the same person
target_image_file_names = ['Family1-Dad1.jpg', 'Family1-Dad2.jpg']
# The source photos contain this person
source_image_file_name1 = 'Family1-Dad3.jpg'
source_image_file_name2 = 'Family1-Son1.jpg'

# Detect face(s) from source image 1, returns a list[DetectedFaces]
# We use detection model 3 to get better performance.
detected_faces1 = face_client.face.detect_with_url(IMAGE_BASE_URL + source_image_file_name1, detection_model='detection_03')
# Add the returned face's face ID
source_image1_id = detected_faces1[0].face_id
print('{} face(s) detected from image {}.'.format(len(detected_faces1), source_image_file_name1))

# Detect face(s) from source image 2, returns a list[DetectedFaces]
detected_faces2 = face_client.face.detect_with_url(IMAGE_BASE_URL + source_image_file_name2, detection_model='detection_03')
# Add the returned face's face ID
source_image2_id = detected_faces2[0].face_id
print('{} face(s) detected from image {}.'.format(len(detected_faces2), source_image_file_name2))

# List for the target face IDs (uuids)
detected_faces_ids = []
# Detect faces from target image url list, returns a list[DetectedFaces]
for image_file_name in target_image_file_names:
    # We use detection model 3 to get better performance.
    detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_url(IMAGE_BASE_URL + image_file_name, detection_model='detection_03')
    # Add the returned face's face ID
    detected_faces_ids.append(detected_faces[0].face_id)
    print('{} face(s) detected from image {}.'.format(len(detected_faces), image_file_name))

# Verification example for faces of the same person. The higher the confidence, the more identical the faces in the images are.
# Since target faces are the same person, in this example, we can use the 1st ID in the detected_faces_ids list to compare.
verify_result_same = face_client.face.verify_face_to_face(source_image1_id, detected_faces_ids[0])
print('Faces from {} & {} are of the same person, with confidence: {}'
    .format(source_image_file_name1, target_image_file_names[0], verify_result_same.confidence)
    if verify_result_same.is_identical
    else 'Faces from {} & {} are of a different person, with confidence: {}'
        .format(source_image_file_name1, target_image_file_names[0], verify_result_same.confidence))
```

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen the line which starts with detected_face1. Basically I am trying to create a function but im unable to do so.

Comment: @RifayeIbrahim you are not using the keyword `def` anywhere, so you are not creating any function. Please provide the full stacktrace.